# Query on artifical gravity via symmetrical tethered rotation

Tags: mars, interplanetary, artificial-gravity

Has there been any consideration to the use of a tether between to identical space vehicles (e.g. two SpaceX Starships) to induce artifical gravity?

I think you would need a diameter that could only be achieved with flexible tether rather than a "bend resistant structure". I imagine however that a tether might be unstable. I am sure the longer term future of space flight will require gravity as zero g is terrible on the body.

Comment: This has been tested [over half a century ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agena_target_vehicle)

Comment: I believe that tethering 2 Starships has been the subject of numerous discussions on forums. One point to note - a nose docking port may not be best placed to take the weight of an entire Starship. I think Robert Zubrin made a case for tethering a Mars transfer habitat module to a spent upper stage in the case for Mars, but that was not a symmetrical arrangement.

Comment: You can also search the site for [tehter*](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=tether*) (327 results!) and questions that have the [space-tether](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-tether) tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tethers in general have been considered, yes. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCwXJMVVdck) by Scott Manley highlights him consulting on the Netflix film Stowaway to discuss the design of a tether-based interplanetary vessel featured in the film.

It's a pretty safe bet that if filmmakers are showing 'crunchy' (well-researched, technically accurate) design schemes for spacecraft, the engineering community has been kicking the idea around for a minute.

As to whether or not identical vessels in particular have been considered, I can't imagine they weren't the first design envisioned when someone looked into the concept - it greatly reduces the necessary math to rough the idea out.

Comment: And yet isaac arthur never mentions it. :/

Comment: One would argue that Isaac Arthur aims to l and bigger fish. His proposed orbital ring scheme is arguably just a continuous electromagnetic tether...